# Будет ли GC очищать null-ы в массивах/коллекциях когда памяти начнет не хватать?

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции, null, сборщик-мусора

Допустим, есть массив:

```
String[] arr = { "a", null, "b" };
```

Если память начнет заканчиваться, будет ли GC удалять `null`? Я думаю, что нет, так как массивы - это не коллекции.
Хорошо, а как быть с коллекциями? Возможно ли такое, что GC, сделав свою работу, "сожмёт" коллекцию, и по старым индексам я получу совсем не то, что хочу?

Comment: Как можно удалить `null`? GC не может менять количество элементов в массиве. Реализация коллекции базируется на массиве.

Comment: @Suvitruf, ну.. В книге Эккеля "Философия Java" написано, что при выходе ссылки из области действия, при потере "связи" над объектом и при установке значения в `null` обьект становится жертвой GC. Я даже где-то в исходниках Java видел такое: установка переменной значения `null` и рядом коммент "Дадим GC делать свою работу"

Comment: @Suvitruf, `реализация коллекции базируется на массиве` - а вот это я не знал :)

Comment: Там речь о другом. Пусть есть `String[] arr = { "a", "b" };` и следующей строкой сделаем `arr = null`, тогда объект `{ "a", "b" }` будет удален, память очистится.

Comment: @Flippy "реализация коллекции базируется на массиве - а вот это я не знал". Это лишь отчасти так. `ArrayList` - лишь одна из реализаций интерфейса `Collection`, другие могут базироваться на чем угодно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` - это не объект, а лишь ссылка. Сборщик мусора не очищает память от ссылок, а лишь от объектов, которых невозможно достичь из текущего "рантайм" состояния кода. Если ссылка находится на стеке (локальная переменная, аргумент метода), она освободится вмести с освобождением её места на стеке (возврат из метода). Если ссылка - это поле класса или элемент массива, то она освободится вмести с освобождением памяти всего объекта (в вашем случае - всего массива).

Answer (score 3):

1. Как можно удалить `null`? Там и так ничего нет.
2. GC не может менять количество элементов в массиве. Получить в ячейках мусор как в C++ нельзя.
3. [`ArrayList` базируется на массиве](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l127).

Comment: "Как можно удалить null? Там и так ничего нет." Вообще, в качестве объяснения тут бы подошло в стиле "что такое null в Java", но можно ли это кратко описать - не знаю

Comment: @Regent https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707333/1991579 (:

Comment: Да-да, я вот как раз тогда думал, можно ли этот ответ как-то компактно уместить в ответе, в разрезе этого вопроса)

Answer (score 2):

Сборщик мусора удаляет из кучи те объекты, на которые нет ссылки. Коллекция ссылается на свои элементы. Так что пока есть ссылка на коллекцию, все её элементы недоступны сборщику.

**UPDATE:**

Чтобы исключить любые разночтения и недопонимания, углубимся в детали. Прежде всего нужно определиться с тем, что же такое `null`. На уровне java-кода `null` - это *ничто*. Если опуститься ниже, на уровень виртуальной машины, то `null` становится неким специальным значением. Это можно увидеть, заглянув в байткод получающийся из `String[] arr = { "a", null, "b" }`:

```
 0: iconst_3
 1: anewarray     #2          // class java/lang/String
 4: dup
 5: iconst_0
 6: ldc           #3          // String a
 8: aastore
 9: dup
10: iconst_1
11: aconst_null               // Загрузка null во вторую ячейку массива
12: aastore
13: dup
14: iconst_2
15: ldc           #4          // String b
17: aastore
18: astore_1
```

Согласно [JLS 4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1), `null` - это ссылка безымянного типа, что не очень интересно в контексте управления памятью. Интереснее, как эта ссылка представлена на ещё более низком уровне - в Сишном коде виртуальной машины. Об этом спецификация ничего не говорит, а значит это зависит от реализации. Например, это может быть указатель на нулевой адрес памяти. В любом случае, этот указатель имеет некоторый размер, зависящий от размера используемой кучи - 4 или 8 байт.

То есть *ничто* занимает до восьми байт как в стеке, так и в куче. Дальше я для простоты буду считать, что все ссылки имеют размер в четыре байта.

Теперь разберёмся в нюансах хранения данных в памяти массивами и коллекциями. В случае массива в куче создаётся объект массива, хранящий в себе (помимо прочего) ссылку на начало непрерывного блока памяти, имеющего размер достаточный, чтобы хранить заданное количество элементов определённого (в соответствии с типом) размера. В случае массива ссылочных типов из трёх элементов, это будет блок памяти из 12 байт. Первые 4 байта будут хранить ссылку на строку "a", вторые четыре байта буду хранить ссылку на нулевой адрес, и последние 4 байта будут хранить ссылку на строку "b".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Даже если игнорировать тот факт, что память под массивы выделяется и освобождается одним куском, всё равно с точки зрения сборщика мусора пустых ячеек в массиве нет.

С коллекциями всё ещё интереснее, так как в них появляется разница между элементом коллекции и значением элемента коллекции. Возьмём для примера [LinkedList](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java). Каждый элемент связанного списка - это объект типа `Node`, хранящий некоторое значение и ссылки на другие элементы. А значит для хранения значения `null` будет создан отдельный объект.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Локальная стековая переменная ссылается на объект типа `LinkedList` в куче, этот объект ссылается на объекты типа `Node`, а они в свою очередь хранят указатели на объекты строк или нулевой адрес памяти. В этот раз для хранения `null` требуется уже около 24 байт - заголовок объекта типа `Node` и три его поля ссылочного типа. И так же с точки зрения сборщика мусора цепочка ссылок неразрывна, все используемые области памяти доступны, удалять нечего.

Comment: Неверное объяснение. Сборщик мусора в Java вообще не считает количество ссылок, а лишь проверяет доступность объекта из текущего "рантайм" состояния кода. Таким образом предотвращаются утечки памяти, когда несколько недоступных, для программы, объектов ссылаются друг на друга. А `null` это даже не объект, а ссылка и никто на неё не ссылается, потому что в Java нельзя ссылаться на ссылку. Посмотрите мой ответ ниже.

Comment: @РостиславКрасный нигде в моём ответе про подсчёт ссылок не написано. И похоже, что вы путаете элемент коллекции со значением элемента коллекции. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Но вы же сами написали, цитирую: "Сборщик мусора удаляет из кучи те объекты, на которые нет ссылки". Что это если не подсчёт ссылок? На самом деле сборщик мусора может удалять и те объекты, на которые есть ссылки, но они всё равно недоступны из текущего состояния кода.

Comment: @РостиславКрасный под "есть ссылка" я имел ввиду достижимость от корней.

Comment: Так неправильно говорить и это точно вводит людей в заблуждение.